# Way to slice a string using 2 variable?

Tags: python, string

I m new to programming and came across a question If I have a string where I have 2 variables indexed.. and need the value from the middle.

for example, my string is `HeyEveryoneImtryingtolearnpythonandihavequestion`
where I have variables

```
V1 = 'Imtrying'
V2 = 'andihave'
```

what can I do to get the "learnpython" substring? or is it not valid?

Comment: Maybe `V1` is `Imtryingto`?

Comment: Yeah, my bad!
One way I found to do this is use replace like..
Relevant = MyString.replace(V1, '@#@')
Relevant2 = MyString.replace(V2, '@##@')

and then do the slicing from @#@ to @##@.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use regex:

```
import re

s = "HeyEveryoneImtryingtolearnpythonandihavequestion"
V1 = 'Imtryingto'
V2 = 'andihave'

a = re.search(f"{re.escape(V1)}(.*?){re.escape(V2)}", s).group(1) # 'learnpython'
```

Comment: Awesome, got the result perfectly!
Didn't think of using regular expression.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend, for the general case, changing this to: `a = re.search(f"{re.escape(V1)}(.*?){re.escape(V2)}", s).group(1)`, in case `V1` or `V2` contain regex specials; otherwise the behavior will differ from using them as non-regex markers. For the described `V1` and `V2` `re.escape` will change nothing, but it's critical for general correctness.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `index` and slicing:

```py
s = 'HeyEveryoneImtryingtolearnpythonandihavequestion'

v1 = 'Imtrying'
v2 = 'andihave'

start = s.index(v1) + len(v1)
end = s.index(v2, start)

output = s[start:end]
print(output) # tolearnpython
```

Comment: You can optimize this a tiny bit (or maybe a lot for a 100 MB string) by changing the `end` computation to `end = s.index(v2, start)`, so you don't even try to look for the end string before the start string (assuming that's the correct logic for your program).

Comment: @ShadowRanger I agree.